# How to use google+ share button?

Tags: google-plus, share-button

I have created a google+ share button ... https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/ ...

It works but it doesnt share any content ... only appear a pop-up share window => I write something into => and this text it share normal ... but not content of my page/ article ... do you know why?

in my body I have this ...

```
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="none" data-height="24" data-href="http://localhost/welcome">ddd</div>
```

Comment: I want to share content inside div tags ... I am not sure if it works in this way

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 kind of Google+ share button.You can use a very simple button to share anything.The properties Google+ gets from meta tags and canonical links.
Here is a link: http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/google-share.html

Answer (score 0):

The share button does not support prefilled text. It only supports sharing the current/specified URL.

The [interactive posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) API does support prefilled text but it also requires more setup to get working.